# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.telephony.gsm.GsmCellLocation.getCid()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

I am facing this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                          
Process: com.kotak.pck.jaimaasaraswati, PID: 8321
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kotak.pck.jaimaasaraswati/com.kotak.pck.jaimaasaraswati.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.telephony.gsm.GsmCellLocation.getCid()' on a null object reference
```

**MainActivity:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.telephony.gsm.GsmCellLocation;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView textGsmCellLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gsmcelllocation);
        TextView textCID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cid);
        TextView textLAC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lac);

        //retrieve a reference to an instance of TelephonyManager
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        GsmCellLocation cellLocation = new GsmCellLocation();
        cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation) telephonyManager.getCellLocation();

        int cid = cellLocation.getCid();
        int lac = cellLocation.getLac();
        textGsmCellLocation.setText("GSM Cell Location: " + cellLocation.toString());
        textCID.setText("GSM Cell id: " + String.valueOf(cid));
        textLAC.setText("GSM Location area code: " + String.valueOf(lac));
    }
}
```

thanks for help.

Comment: Obviously `telephonyManager.getCellLocation()` is returning `null`.

Comment: So what should i do for getting the cell info? Is there any other way? or am i making some mistake due to which its returning null?

Comment: The `getCellLocation` method returns `null` if the current location is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getCellLocation()), `getCellLocation()` will return

> Current location of the device or null if not available.

It also requires the following permission.

```
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```

Also, May be it was causing problem due to LTE. As per documentation,

> If there is only one radio in the device and that radio has an LTE connection, this method will return null.

Moreover, you need to use `getAllCellInfo()`, as the other one is deprecated in API level 26.

Comment: This must be useful 3 years ago but a bit too late now... :)